# Tengo un error en mi código de C++

Tags: c++

**Estoy practicando un con un pequeño programa en que quiero que haga las operaciones aritméticas y le doy un menú para que el usuario elija si salir o continuar, el problema es que cuando escribo while al final, me dice que hay un error en la variable "a" que no esta definida pero ya lo hice.**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  do{
     int a, b;

     cout << "opcion 1: sumar\n";
     cout << "opcion 2: restar\n";
     cout << "opcion 3: salir\n";
     cin >> a;

     switch (a){
        case 1:
            cout << "has elegido la opción sumar\n";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "has elegido la opcion restar\n";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Seguro que quieres salir?\n";
            cout << "\n 1) SI";
            cout << "\n 2) NO";
            cin >> b;
            if (b == 1) {
                return 0;
            }
            else 
            {
                return main();
            }
       }
     }while (a!=3);
      system("pause");
      return main();
   }
```

Comment: No deberías llamar a la función main.

Comment: mueve `int a, b;` fuera del `do / while`, tienen que ser variables globales.

Answer (score 0):

Es porque declaraste la variable `a` dentro del DO. Entonces el while no la toma.

Declárala luego del main, así:

```
int main(){
    int a, b;
    do {
        ...
    } while (a != 3);
    ...
}
```

Comment: El  Peruano del video mintió, por que le corrió y así lo tenia... Te lo agradezco.